# Using radio buttons and select fields in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

Quick question:

I have a form that has 8 selectable radio buttons for an attribute :mvp, and a select drop-down menu at the end. I want the user to be able to press a radio button for one of the corresponding values, or not select a radio button and pick an option from the select drop-down menu. They can't both select a radio button and an option from the select field. Here's my code. Please advise.

**HTML**

```
<%= form_for(current_user.awards.build) do |f| %>
<%= f.radio_button :mvp, 'Stephen Curry' %>
<%= f.radio_button :mvp, 'Lebron James' %>
<%= f.radio_button :mvp, 'Kevin Durant' %>
<%= f.radio_button :mvp, 'Russell Westbrook' %>
<%= f.radio_button :mvp, 'Kawhi Leonard' %>
<%= f.radio_button :mvp, 'Karl-Anthony Towns' %>
<%= f.radio_button :mvp, 'Chris Paul' %>
<%= f.select :mvp, ['Al Horford', 'Al Jefferson', 'Andre Drummond', 'Andre Igoudala','Andrew Wiggins', 'Anthony Davis', 'Austin Rivers', 'Ben Simmons', 'Blake Griffin', 'Brook Lopez', 'Carmelo Anthony', 'Chandler Parsons','Chris Bosh', 'Damian Lillard', 'Deandre Jordan', 'Demar Derozan', 'Demarcus Cousins', 'Derrick Favors', 'Dirk Nowitzki', 'Draymond Green', 'Dwight Howard', 'Dwyane Wade', 'Eric Bledsoe', 'Giannis Antetokounmpo', 'Greg Monroe', 'Goran Dragic', 'Gordon Hayward', 'Harrison Barnes','Hassan Whiteside', 'Isaiah Thomas', 'Jahlil Okafor', 'James Harden', 'James Jones','Jeff Teague', 'Jimmy Butler', 'John Wall', 'Kemba Walker','Kevin Love', 'Khris Middleton', 'Klay Thompson', 'Kristaps Porzingis', 'Kyle Lowry', 'Kyrie Irving', 'Lamarcus Aldridge', 'Marc Gasol', 'Mike Conley', 'Nerlens Noel', 'Nicolas Batum', 'Nikola Pekovic', 'Pau Gasol', 'Paul George', 'Paul Millsap','Ricky Rubio','Rudy Gobert', 'Victor Oladipo', 'Zach Lavine'],  include_blank: "Select One" %>
<%= f.submit "Submit Pick" %>
```

As of now if I try to fill in the form, no matter what option I press in the radio buttons, the value that always gets submitted is the one in the select box. I've added an include_blank: option at the end of the select field, but then the value that gets submitted is just a blank value. So for some reason, the default submission is whatever is picked in the select field.